# How do I get the path of the "/Library/Containers/" directory

Tags: swift, macos, sandbox

A sandboxed macOS app can easily access data in two folders:

1. ~/Library/Containers/ProgramName/
2. ~/Library/Group Containers/SecurityGroupName/

The following code will give me the "~/Library/Group Container/" path ...

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let directory = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "myGroup")
print("path:",directory)
```

This will print:

> path: /Users/myName/Library/Group Containers/myGroup

I want to get the path of the "~/Library/**Containers**/" directory, not the "~/Library/**Group Containers**/" directory.

This must be easy to do, as it is a common directory.

Does anybody know how to do this using a Swift function?

I know I can just create it with:

```
var path: String = "/Users/etc/Containers/" + programName
```

Answer (score 4):

In the sandbox the API

```
let url = try FileManager.default.url(for: .libraryDirectory,
                                      in: .userDomainMask,
                                      appropriateFor: nil,
                                      create: false)
```

points to the user library of the container of the current app.

```
file:///Users/myself/Library/Containers/com.myself.Greatapp/Data/Library/
```

You don't have access to the higher level folder `~/Library/Containers`

**Update:**

In iOS 16+, macOS 13+ there is a shortcut, it returns the URL to the `Library` folder of the current user. If the app is sandboxed the URL points to folder in the application container otherwise to the folder in the home folder

```
let url = URL.libraryDirectory
```

Comment: I tried that with "print(url)" and got... file:///Users/myName/Library/ and not what you got ... file:///Users/myself/Library/Containers/com.myself.Greatapp/Data/Library/.  Are you sure your answer is correct ?

Comment: If you get  `file:///Users/myName/Library/` then your app is not sandboxed.

Comment: Oops - I wasn't sandboxed - Now, I am getting a containerPath like yours - many thanks ... Ian