SQLite not working on macOS using SwiftUI with the App Sandbox
I have written a macOS application using SwiftUI (IDE Xcode).  The application stores its data in SQLite database files using the SQLite3 library (import SQLite3).  The application works perfectly with the App Sandbox turned off, but I went to the trouble of creating and saving “secure bookmarks” so that it would also work with the App Sandbox turned on.  With the Sandbox turned on I can SELECT data from the SQLite files outside the sandbox, but I cannot write to the files.
The issue appears to be that the App sandbox is blocking temporary journal files created by SQLite  during write actions.  These files seem to be created in the same directory as the SQLite database files.  The error message generated for database Test.xyz is:
open(/Users/username/Desktop/Test.xyz-journal) - Operation not permitted

Note the file being blocked is Test.xyz-journal and not the is the SQLite database file Test.xyz.
The App Sandbox Guide (Reference 1) has a section where it mentions that SQLite journal files are automatically catered for:

Note: In the case of a SQLite journal file, beginning in 10.8.2, journal files, write-ahead logging files, and shared memory files are automatically added to the related items list if you open a SQLite database, so this step is unnecessary

So I was not expecting issues with the sandbox, but this guide is old (2014) so maybe this behaviour has changed (or I am missing some configuration setting or missing other “steps”).  Perhaps I need to make edits to the Info.plist file, and if so it would be great if someone could provide a clear example.  As I am writing this, I think this is where I may have gone wrong.
I note there is a stackoverflow post from 2019
(Reference 2)
which sounds similar but is having issues with WAL files.
In trying to solve this, I have read about using a package (effectively a directory posing as a file) for the application document file.  I suspect this would work, but it does not suit my application.
My next thought was to work around the problem by getting SQLite to save its temporary files inside the sandbox:
I tried setting the system environment variables:
let path_inside_sandbox = "/Users/username/Library/Containers/…/tmp"
setenv("SQLITE_TMPDIR", path_inside_sandbox, 1)     // this was recommended in the SQLite documentation

and also tried
setenv("TMPDIR", path_inside_sandbox, 1)   // this seems to for older SQLite implementations

I confirmed these environment variables were being set, but SQLite seemed to ignore them on macOS.
I next tried the non-recommended approach of setting the SQLite global variable sqlite3_temp_directory
let unsafePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(mutating: (path_inside_sandbox as NSString).utf8String)
sqlite3_temp_directory = unsafePointer

This also did not seem to change where SQLite saved temporary files on macOS.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!  Either helping me to get the App Sandbox to permit journal files, or getting SQLite to alter where temporary files are saved in macOS.  Or other ideas!

Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71890947/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-library-containers-directory, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278869/file-access-in-a-sandboxed-mac-app-with-swift

Thank you Joakim, I really appreciate you taking the time to reply.  The 2nd link I had already found and it is certainly very useful for anyone trying to get file access outside the sandbox to persist.  My question is more about what is sometimes termed "sidecar file loading", where access is granted to a file (in my case test.xyz) but you need to also grant access to a related file (in my case test.xyz-journal).

Any reason why you can’t have the database file itself inside the sandbox?

Joakim, sorry, no I can't do that.  I've posted some solutions below for others.

Go YOLO mode. Use MEMORY or OFF as the journal mode to eliminate the WAL file from forming. I used this as a technique to not need a package for a document file.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstoredescription/1640598-setvalue

Thanks Warren, yes I agree that works!  It is what I ended up doing.

After exploring this further, I think I have independently gone down all the same dead-ends that aa599 went down in Reference 2 (see original post above).  Unless someone with some stronger knowledge on how to get the App Sandbox to allow sidecar files generated by external libraries (in this case SQLite) answers, we’ll all continue to google around fruitlessly.  As noted above, Reference 1 suggests it is possible.
Best solution so far...
The best solution appears to be using a package (implemented I believe using a swiftUI FileWrapper).  For some clues on how to set this up, see for example,
Create custom document type with FileWrapper.
The idea is that the package, which is effectively a directory posing as a file, contains the SQLite database.  When the user opens the package the sandbox allows writing of files in the whole package and so the SQLite journal files will not be blocked.  Please note I have not verified this approach, but it seems logical it would work.
Unfortunately, this solution does not work for me as, for other reasons, I can’t change the file type.
So, if you’d like some work-arounds …
Work-around solution 1
After the user opens the SQLite database from a file open dialog use:
FileManager.copyItem(at: URL, to: URL)

to copy the database to a location inside the App Sandbox, then get the application to use this copy.  When the user has finished with the database (or at application close) you can then overwrite the original database by copying back.
Yes, its clunky but it works in my tests.  One thing to bear in mind is that the final overwrite will cause any saved secure bookmark to become stale, and so you cannot programmatically re-open the database unless it is first opened by the user again.  For many, that won’t matter, but it stopped me using this work-around.
Work-around solution 2
SQLite can be directed to write the journal file to memory rather than to a file as follows:
var connection: OpaquePointer? 

// create your connection as usual here

let SQLStr = "PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY"
sqlite3_exec(connection, SQLStr, nil, nil, nil)

This bypasses the sandbox problem altogether as there is no physical journal file.  Note, as far as I understand, there is a slightly greater chance of the database becoming corrupted with this setting if the application crashes during a database write.  To counter this, I simply back up the database to a location inside the application support directory, so that in the worst case not all is lost.
This is the solution I ended up using.
